# How to Play a Sound Effect with a Audio Graph

Tags: ios, audio

I have an AudioGraph that I'm using for bi-directional audio communication.  I'd like to also play some sound effects (Using System Sound Services) while the graph is started, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The sound effects play perfectly fine when is the graph is stopped.

Can these two audio frameworks be used together in this way?  Is there something special I need to do to mix the output together?

Comment: Search audio unit / render callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code for effects or processing in the corresponding callback function. For a specific example,

InputRenderCallback()

in Apple's MixerHost sample project.